# How to serialize a string-valued property as a string array

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, json.net

I have a class:

```
Public Class ExtraInfo
   Property extratypes As String
End Class
```

I have a form submitted and the value assign is string, the data submitted from form is string not array:

```
extratypes = '1,2';
```

Now when I save into the database as json:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(edited)
```

it give me this in json:

```
{"extratypes":"1,2"}
```

How can I manipulate it to string array before saving it like the one below:

```
{"extratypes":["1","2"]}
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be appropriate to introduce a class for extratypes where you can have an array of string for the serialization and then override ToString  to print the array as a concatenated string.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array in your model:

```
Public Class ExtraInfo
   Property extratypes() As String
End Class
```

and then [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) the value that comes from the user input before assigning it to this property.

Comment: yah, but I  want it to be string, but at later stage change it to string array before saving, because the string is from a form, it is not array.

Comment: Then use a different model for the serialization. And copy the properties from the one to the other. And when copying the `extratypes` property use the Split method. Now when you JSON serialize you will get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy property that translates your string to and from an array.  Decorate the original property with [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) and the proxy with [`[JsonProperty("extratypes")]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).  You can make the proxy property private if that's convenient and Json.NET will serialize it as long as it has the `[JsonProperty]` attribute:

```
Public Class ExtraInfo

    <JsonIgnore()> _
    Public Property extratypes As String

    <JsonProperty("extratypes")> _
    Private Property extratypesArray As String()
        Get
            If extratypes Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            End If
            Return extraTypes.Split(","c)

        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String())
            If value Is Nothing Then
                extratypes = Nothing
            Else
                extratypes = String.Join(","c, value)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DNPDby).

Other option would be to write your own [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).