# convert string in json to string array

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am trying to convert json string "1,2" to `["1","2"]`, but I got this "[1,2]":

```
Dim json = {"types": "1,2"}
oAction.ExtraData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json)

Dim extraData As JObject
extraData = JObject.Parse(oAction.ExtraData)
extraData("types") = "[" + extraData("types").ToString + "]"

oAction.ExtraData  = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(types)
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you are trying to do? `{"types": ["1","2"]}` will   deserialize to a string array.

Comment: it is "types":"1,2" in json.

Comment: And that is why i asked if you could explain more,  Are you trying to convert the deserialized json or create json of a specific type?

Comment: I want to convert "1, 2" to ["1", "2"].

Comment: How does this question differ from your other question: [Convert data type from string to string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249342/convert-data-type-from-string-to-string-array/34256939)?